# How to change a function with Option to work in both cases

Tags: scala

I need to change the the definition of the function selectSeq which should now work with old call and new a call which slightly differ.

This code is a part of my project.

```
  def selectSeq(option0: Option[String] = Some("- Choose -")): Future[Seq[(String, String)]] = db.run {
    tableQuery().result.map { locations =>
      (option0 match {
        case Some(option0) => Seq(("0", option0))
        case None => Seq()
      })
    }
  }
```

Now, I call this function by

```
selectSeq(Some("any"))
```

I need to change this function to also accept call the

```
selectSeq(Some("","any"))
```

and obtain `Seq(("", option0))`. I have tried already the following definition

```
 def selectSeq(option0: Option[(String,String)] = Some("","- Choose-")
```

which accepts call

```
selectSeq(Some("","any")
```

but it doesn't work with an old call. Please, how to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

Consider *overloading* the method by providing a definition of a method with the same name `selectSeq` but different signature like so:

```
def selectSeq(option0: Option[(String, String)] = Some("","- Choose-")): Future[Seq[(String, String)]] = db.run {
    tableQuery().result.map { locations =>
      (option0 match {
        ...
      })
    }
  }

def selectSeq(option0: Option[String] = Some("- Choose -")): Future[Seq[(String, String)]] = db.run {
    ...
```

Compiler will be able to figure out which definition to call, because despite the two methods having the same name, they have different types, namely

```
Option[(String, String)] => Future[Seq[(String, String)]]
```

vs

```
Option[String] => Future[Seq[(String, String)]]
```

---

Applying the comment, to avoid overloading, consider defining your own ADT and then pattern matching like so

```
sealed trait Foo
case class Bar(v: String) extends Foo
case class Qux(v: (String,String)) extends Foo

def selectSeq(foo: Option[Foo] = Some(Bar("- Choose -"))): Future[Seq[(String, String)]] = db.run {
    tableQuery().result.map { locations =>
      (option0 match {
        case Some(Bar(v)) => ...
        case Some(Qux((a,b)) => ...
        ...
      })
    }
  }
}

selectSeq(Some(Bar("any")))
selectSeq(Some(Qux("","any")))
```

Comment: Thx, overloading is a good way, but is it possible to do that without that? Just by changing function parameters and then adding some match options?

Comment: Consider defining your own ADT and then pattern matching on individual cases, as shown in the edited answer.